# Getting a string from a second column in Lua

Tags: split, lua

I'm working in a script in Lua and I have a problem.
I need to look for a string in a file and get the string next to it (every line of the string has an string a coma and the second string).
An example of the file could be:
File Data.txt

```
Data11,Data12
Data21,Data22
Data31,Data32
```

I'm using the program:

```
function getmatches(text)
print(pattern)
for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
m,n = string.match(line,"**Data11**[^,]*,([^,]+)")
if m ~= nil then 
print(m) 
end
end
end


local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
local file = open(path, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
if not file then return nil end
local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
file:close()
return content
end


local fileContent = read_file("Data.txt");
getmatches(fileContent)
```

This program works but has the pattern hardcoded and it changes.
What I need is giving an extra value to the getmatches function like getmatches(filecontent,pattern_string)
and in the function replace **Data11** for the value of pattern_string, so I can call the function from another program with different values of pattern_string.
I'm using Lua 5.4.2.
Thanks in advance.

This is the program I have right now:

```
function getmatches(text)
for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
m,n = string.match(line,"Data11[^,]*,([^,]+)")
if m ~= nil then 
print(m) 
end
end
end


local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
local file = open(path, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
if not file then return nil end
local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
file:close()
return content
end


local fileContent = read_file("Datos2.txt");
print (fileContent);

getmatches(fileContent)
```

It works with the value of the string I'm looking for in the code and this value must change so I need to pass this value to the function getmatches(text, pattern) and it has to be used in the line m,n = string.match(line,"Data11[^,]*,([^,]+)") as the value o variable pattern instead Data11.
I don't get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: `m = string.match(line, pattern.."[^,]*,([^,]+)")`

Comment: `Data11[^,]*` checks that `Data11` is a prefix for the first value; it does not check that the first value *is* Data11. What do you want?

Comment: Also, do you want `pattern` to be treated as a pattern, or as a literal string? If I pass `pattern = "a*"`, should it match `a` followed by a literal asterisk or zero or more `a`s?

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
I didn´t express pretty well. Maybe with the program and comments I'll explain better.

Comment: @Eskri, Luatic First of all, thank you all for your help.
Maybe with the program and comments I'll explain better. In the next Comment.
function getmatches(text,pattern) -- pattern is what I have to look for 
 for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
  m = string.match(line, pattern.."[^,]*,([^,]+)") -- I think since pattern in the file doesn't have " " it doesn't work
  if m ~= nil then 
  print(m) 
  end
 end
return m
end
local fileContent = read_file("Data.txt");
local NHCold=Dato11
NHCnew = getmatches(fileContent,NHCold) -- NHCnew should be Dato12

Comment: Change: `Dato11` -> `"Dato11"`